# Common string values for localization

Tags: android, string, localization

I need to implement localization by adding values-fr & values-ar. There are common strings that no need for users to be shown like  (admob-banner-id), lvl, .....;
My question is: shall I include those common strings in each values-xx? or it's enough to keep it in values folder for one time?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `values/strings.xml`, in non translatable strings, add this : `translatable="false"`. For example :

```
<string name="hello" translatable="false">Do not translate me</string>
```

Comment: Great, Thanks very much.

Comment: @AtefFarouk You're welcome. Please accept the answer to close the question ;) Thanks